# Solr pagination giving duplicate results when used with geodist function

Tags: solr, pagination

```
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":1,
"params":{
  "sort":"geodist(geo, 12.919185299999999,77.6686028) asc",
  "fl":"dist:geodist(geo,12.919185299999999,77.6686028) health_institute_name",
  "indent":"true",
  "start":"24",
  "q":"*:*",
  "wt":"json",
  "fq":"institute_address_cityid:1",
  "rows":"48"}},


"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "sort":"geodist(geo, 12.919185299999999,77.6686028) asc",
      "fl":"dist:geodist(geo,12.919185299999999,77.6686028) health_institute_name",
      "indent":"true",
      "start":"49",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json",
      "fq":"institute_address_cityid:1",
      "rows":"60"}},
```

above are the 2 pagination conditions but both resulting in duplicate results can anyone please help me resolve this issue
Thanks

Comment: There's obviously going to be overlap. Look at your `start` and `rows` values. You clearly have the potential to have 23 rows that are the same.

Comment: the problem was that rows were being updated along with the start, keeping the rows constant has solved the problem, thanks for the input.